# How do I get the top-5 devices by value from a table of IoT sensors in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I have a table that looks like the following:

| prob | name | freq | lim | count | hash | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0755 | ard | 0.988 | 0.633 | 0 | 5YIF6HSOtHN9HdcE5IPzMe | 2021-04-09T10:56:00.986441Z |
| 0.0755 | ard | 0.988 | 0.633 | 0 | 5YIF6HSOtHN9HdcE5IPzMe | 2021-04-09T10:56:00.986441Z |
| 0.0006259999999999999 | srd2 | 0.987 | 0.649 | 0 | 5GFwJHucflHj46Hwet6qvc | 2021-04-09T10:56:14.799226Z |
| 0.0006259999999999999 | ard2 | 0.987 | 0.649 | 0 | 5GFwJHucflHj46Hwet6qvc | 2021-04-09T10:56:14.799226Z |
| 0.0006259999999999999 | ard2 | 0.987 | 0.649 | 0 | 5GFwJHucflHj46Hwet6qvc | 2021-04-09T10:56:14.799226Z |
| 0.145 | ard12 | 0.986 | 0.597 | 1 | 1MgM0WDaoQ2A3bnIQTR6ty | 2021-04-09T10:56:15.309345Z |
| 0.145 | ard12 | 0.986 | 0.597 | 1 | 1MgM0WDaoQ2A3bnIQTR6ty | 2021-04-09T10:56:15.309345Z |

I would like to have top-5 sensors by name according to some other value, let's say

- top 5 devices by `prob`

of course if I do

```sql
select * from my_sensors order by prob DESC
```

then I have some duplicates by sensor name and LIMIT is not working because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do in this case is use `WITH` which allows sub-queries:

```sql
WITH top_devices AS (select DISTINCT name, prob from my_sensors order by prob DESC)
select * from top_devices limit 5;
```

This will return two columns with the sensor name and `prob` column:

| name | prob |
| --- | --- |
| ard12 | 0.145 |
| ard | 0.0755 |
| ard2 | 0.0006259999999999999 |
| ... | ... |

There are only three unique sensors in your example, but I presume the full dataset would give you top 5.

To get rid of dupes, the example query here is using `DISTINCT`

References:

- [WITH keyword docs](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/with)
- [DISTINCT keyword docs](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/distinct)